# Problem installing tidyverse package "error in loadspacename"

Tags: r, rstudio, tidyverse

Newly installed R and R studio on windows 10 computer and now it won't install the tidyverse package.

I have tried restarting, re-installing and the advice seen other places of using dependencies=true or installing broom before installing tidyverse and none of it worked.

Had to shorten the output because of too many links

Help would be greatly appreciated

```
install.packages("tidyverse")

also installing the dependencies ‘Rcpp’, ‘dplyr’, ‘purrr’, ‘rlang’, ‘broom’, ‘dbplyr’, ‘ggplot2’, ‘modelr’


  There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
         binary source needs_compilation
Rcpp    0.12.16  1.0.0              TRUE
dplyr     0.7.4  0.7.8              TRUE
purrr     0.2.4  0.3.0              TRUE
rlang     0.2.0  0.3.1              TRUE
broom     0.4.4  0.5.1             FALSE
dbplyr    1.2.1  1.3.0             FALSE
ggplot2   2.2.1  3.1.0             FALSE
modelr    0.1.1  0.1.2             FALSE

 
package ‘Rcpp’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘dplyr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘purrr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘rlang’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘tidyverse’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\rhas0020\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpWkjzuk\downloaded_packages
installing the source packages ‘broom’, ‘dbplyr’, ‘ggplot2’, ‘modelr’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/broom_0.5.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1230196 bytes (1.2 MB)
downloaded 1.2 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/dbplyr_1.3.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 269092 bytes (262 KB)
downloaded 262 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/ggplot2_3.1.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2863109 bytes (2.7 MB)
downloaded 2.7 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/modelr_0.1.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 118432 bytes (115 KB)
downloaded 115 KB

* installing *source* package 'broom' ...
** package 'broom' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called 'pillar'
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'broom'
* removing 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.3.2/library/broom'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.2/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.2\library" C:\Users\rhas0020\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpWkjzuk/downloaded_packages/broom_0.5.1.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘broom’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package 'dbplyr' ...
** package 'dbplyr' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace 'dplyr' 0.7.4 is being loaded, but >= 0.7.5 is required
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'dbplyr'
* removing 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.3.2/library/dbplyr'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.2/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.2\library" C:\Users\rhas0020\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpWkjzuk/downloaded_packages/dbplyr_1.3.0.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘dbplyr’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package 'ggplot2' ...
** package 'ggplot2' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  namespace 'rlang' 0.2.0 is being loaded, but >= 0.2.1 is required
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'ggplot2'
* removing 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.3.2/library/ggplot2'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.2/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.2\library" C:\Users\rhas0020\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpWkjzuk/downloaded_packages/ggplot2_3.1.0.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ggplot2’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency 'broom' is not available for package 'modelr'
* removing 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.3.2/library/modelr'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.2/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.2\library" C:\Users\rhas0020\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpWkjzuk/downloaded_packages/modelr_0.1.2.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘modelr’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\rhas0020\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpWkjzuk\downloaded_packages’
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying several different things including downloading and unpacking "pillar" and "broom" and others wihtout success I finally "solved" the issue by uninstalling and reinstalling RStudio again - now it works..